# iOS swift Operation Queue

Tags: swift, concurrency, nsoperationqueue, nsoperation, operation

I am working on iOS app where I am using OperationQueue. I have created 2 operations. Operation2 is dependent on completion of Operation1.Operation2 needs to wait until Operation 1 get finished if its running. If operation 1 is not running then operation 2 should start immediately.

Its not working as expected so I am testing in playground

```
    class MyManager {

        var operationQueue: OperationQueue?

        var operation1: MyOperation? = nil
        var operation2: MyOperation? = nil

        typealias completion = (_ serverError: String?) -> Void

        func talkWithServer(completion: completion?) {

            completion?("competed!")
        }

        func doOperation1() {

            cancelProcess()
            setup()

            guard let operation1 = self.operation1 else { return }
            operation1.codeToRun = {
                print("operation1 started")
                self.talkWithServer(completion: { (completion) in
                    print("operation1 completed")
                    operation1.markAsFinished()
                })
            }
            operationQueue?.addOperation(operation1)

        }


        func doOperation2() {
           self.operation2 = MyOperation()

            guard let operation2 = self.operation2 else { return }



            operation2.codeToRun = {
                print("operation2 started")
                self.talkWithServer(completion: { (completion) in
                    print("operation2 completed")
                    operation2.markAsFinished()
                })
            }

if let operation1 = self.operation1 {
            if operation1.isExecuting {
                operation2.addDependency(operation1)
                operation1.completionBlock = {
                    print("operation1.completionBlock")
                    self.operationQueue?.addOperation(operation2)
                }
            }
            } else  {
                operationQueue?.addOperation(operation2)
            }

        }


        func cancelProcess() {
            print("cancelAllOperations")
            operationQueue?.cancelAllOperations()
        }

        func setup() {
            print("setup Called")
            operationQueue?.cancelAllOperations()
            operationQueue = OperationQueue()
            operation1 = MyOperation()
            operation2 = MyOperation()
        }
    }


    class MyOperation: Operation {
        var codeToRun: (()->Void)?

        var _executing = false
        var _finished = false

        override internal(set) var isExecuting: Bool {
            get {
                return _executing
            }
            set {
                _executing = newValue

            }
        }

        override internal(set) var isFinished: Bool {
            get {
                return _finished
            }
            set {
                _finished = newValue
            }
        }

        override var isAsynchronous: Bool {
            return true
        }

        override func start() {
            isExecuting = true
            isFinished = false
            if let closure = self.codeToRun {
                closure()
            }
        }

        func markAsFinished() {
            self.isExecuting = false
            self.isFinished = true
            completionBlock?()
        }
    }

    let manager = MyManager()

    manager.doOperation1()
    manager.doOperation2()
```

I am getting result

```
cancelAllOperations
setup Called
operation1 started
operation1 completed
operation1.completionBlock
```

Expected is

```
cancelAllOperations
setup Called
operation1 started
operation1 completed
operation1.completionBlock
operation2 started
operation2 completed
```

Am I missing here anything?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. You have written in the 2nd line of your question that operation2 can start after operation1 is in progress or completed. Is this a typo because if you add dependency it will wait till operation1 completes. Why are you setting the `codeToRun` after adding it to the queue. It needs to be done before adding it to the queue.

Comment: Is this implementation of your operation copied from somewhere ? There are a number of issues with your code. Could you please the read the documentation of Operation.

Comment: codeToRun is set before adding to queue. Corrected.

Comment: Do you want the 2nd operation to start after the 1st operation completes ? If so could you edit your 2nd line of your question ?

Comment: Corrected Thanks

Comment: Two ways to look into achieving this are to add operation1 as a dependency of operation2 but of course it you never have an operation1 for some reason that fails.  The other method is to set the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` property of the operation queue to 1 so that only 1 operation can execute at any time.  Then if operation1 starts first operation2 has to wait for it but if there is no operation1 operation 2 will just start.  Doing this the operations will execute in the order they are added and each one waits for the previous one to finish.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking at your code. I found a few things:

#### First

```
manager.doOperation1()
manager.doOperation2()
```

this not means operation2 runs after operation1 finished, if you want to do this, you can add a completion closure for operation1.

#### Second

when you call

```
doOperation2()
```

in this function seems like the code never executed after:

```
guard let operation2 = self.operation2 else { return }
```

#### After all

It seems like you want to create your own wheels. I suggest you to learn something about GCD,you can find resources here:

[Grand Central Dispatch Crash Course for Swift 3](https://medium.com/modernnerd-code/grand-central-dispatch-crash-course-for-swift-3-8bf2652c1cb8)

[Grand Central Dispatch Tutorial for Swift 3: Part 1/2](https://www.raywenderlich.com/148513/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-3-part-1)

Comment: Thanks for documentation. I would like to use OperationQueue instead of GCD. I am trying to figure out why dependency is not working

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things:

## Implementation:

- Implement `KVO` for `isExecuting` and `isFinished`
- Fix `doOperation2`
- Once you set the dependencies the `operation2` wouldn't start even if it is added to the queue until `operation1` completes.
- Check for isCancelled inside `MyOperation`

Below is not the ideal way to implement `doOperation2`, but removes some of the clutter from your code. I will leave it to you to implement the whole thing based on the Design section mentioned below.

```
func doOperation2() {

    self.operation2 = MyOperation()

    guard let operation2 = self.operation2 else {
        return
    }

    operation2.codeToRun = {
        print("operation2 started")

        self.talkWithServer(completion: { (completion) in
            print("operation2 completed")
        })
    }

    operationQueue?.addOperation(operation2)
}
```

## Design:

- In your implementation, `MyOperation` seems to be generic and you seem to be doing most of the real work at the place where you call them
- Modify `MyOperation` to do the real work.
- Call site should be simple
- Example `FetchData()` is an operation, `ParseData()` is another operation.
- So an operation contains business logic.
- At the call site you can just add dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is just add dependency on the dependent operation.

```
let queue = OperationQueue()

let operation1 = BlockOperation(block: { [weak self] in
    self?.doOperation1()
})

let operation2 = BlockOperation(block: { [weak self] in
    self?.doOperation2()
})

operation1.addDependency(operation2) // THIS IS THE KEY CODE IN YOUR CASE

queue.addOperation(operation1)
queue.addOperation(operation2)
```

Hope this may help you solve your dependency problem.